# Шасси и карты

Tags: железо

На работе часто встречается выражение "шасси, на которых крепятся карты, на которых находятся порты". Подскажите нубу, кое-какую информацию по подобной тематике (ссылки рекомендуются).

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что проблемы с железом не являются допустимой темой Stackoverflow на русском языке.

Comment: @decyrus, кто сказал?

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял вопрос, здесь под "шасси" имеются ввиду разъёмы на материнской плате для подключения периферийных устройств (например слоты PCI).![alt text][1]А вот, например, карта на которой находятся порты USB:![alt text][2]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/baX5Q.jpg  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGugX.jpg